# multiple fields of compound index cannot be arrays

Tags: aws-documentdb-mongoapi, aws-documentdb

I am getting this error while migrating data from mongodb to documentdb.  Indexes were created on documentdb side without problems.

```
2019-04-26T17:40:20.118+0000    error: multiple fields of compound index cannot be arrays
2019-04-26T17:40:20.445+0000    error: multiple fields of compound index cannot be arrays
2019-04-26T17:40:22.057+0000    error: multiple fields of compound index cannot be arrays
```

I see similar questions asked way back about mongodb, how is documentdb implementation differ from it?  I did not see any issues while creating indexes in documentdb, only see it in restore during the restore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB does not yet support creating a compound index with multiple keys on the same array. A workaround is to create individual indexes on the desired array fields, as the Amazon DocumentDB query planner is capable of using multiple indexes in a single query.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to MongoDB, Amazon DocumentDB does not support more than one array field in a compound index.